# Child table not having parent's id as foreign key - JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Maybe a very obvious answer exists but I cant see it.
I have a parent table Parent and a child Table Child.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

   @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
   private int parentId;

   @JsonBackReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Child> childs;
   ....
}
```

And the child entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {
   @EmbeddedId
   private ChildPK id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false,      referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
   private Parent parent;
   ....
}
```

The composite primary key being:

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {

   @Column(name="CTGRY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private int ctgryId;

   @Column(name="PARENT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private int parentId;
   ....
}
```

Now in my service method, i set the relation both ways

```
childItem.setParent(parent);

parent.setChilds(childItemList);
```

and call save on the entity:

```
parentDao.save(parent);
```

This creates a new entry for the PARENT table as expected with a pk generated by the table identity. Creates a new insert in the CHILD table as expected with a pk generated by the table identity.
However, the fk of the child entry should have been the parentId, but it comes as 0!

Am i missing something?
Although this problem is not unique, when I tried looking for similar issues online, few of the suggestions didn't appear to be relevant.

Please let me know in case you need more details.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are making both id's entries not insertable (one must be insertable, or the JPA implementation wont know from where take the id):

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonManagedReference
@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false,      referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
private Parent parent;
```

And

```
@Column(name="PARENT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private int parentId;
```

You should remove the **insertable = false** from parent object (first example).
Other option is removing the insertable false from the second one and making it "by hand" in the @prepersist:

```
@PrePersist
protected setIdsBeforeSave() {
    this.id = new ChildPK(parent.Id, categoryId);
}
```

**Edit**

**Option 1**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {
   @EmbeddedId
   private ChildPK id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
   private Parent parent;
   ....
}
```

And the other classes remain the same

**Option 2**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child implements Serializable {
   @EmbeddedId
   private ChildPK id;
   ....
   @PrePersist
   protected void setIdsBeforeSave() {
       //You set the parent ID, so wont be null, idk what category means, that why i just put the 0
       this.id = new ChildPK(parent.Id, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: The first option results in                                                                              Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory                                                  Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Child column: PARENT_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") Sorry about the poor formatting.

Comment: Also regarding the other option (@PrePersist): I dont have a id column in the ChildPK class. It just has a parentId and a categoryId. So what is expected here?

Comment: Did you remove the insertable=false just from one field?, or two?, and, for the second option, te prepersist method must be in the child class, not the chilld pk, editing the answer to reflect that